# one colormap for multiple subplots with different maximum values

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I want to do two subplots with imshow using the same colormap by which I mean: if points in both plots have the same color, they correspond to the same value. But how can I get imshow to use only 9/10 or so of the colormap for the first plot, because it's maximal value is only 9/10 of the maximal value in the second plot?

Thanks,
Alice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imgshow` takes two arguments `vmin` and `vmax` for the color scale. You could do what you want by putting the same `vmin` and `vmax` for both your subplots.

To find `vmin` you can take the minimum between the minimum of all the values in your data (and same reasoning for `vmax`).